# In your pocket for awhile

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

In your pocket I'll stay till you send me away;

But keep me a while and I'll build up a pile,

Lest for desire I'll escape all a-fire.

What am I?

*(haha I made this one up myself)*

Comment: I guess that was too easy, eh?

Comment: Yep, 'fraid so! So was your last rebus :-)

Comment: Okay, okay, I'll try harder.  This is the first one I actually made up though.  I publish a childrens' magazine, and had a riddle contest and my other rebus puzzles were created by them.

Comment: But I can't use all their riddles!  Look at this one: *I am pink; I like mud and water but I am not a pig.  I have a beak and I fly.  What am I?*  I am at least conscientious enough not to post that one!  So you see I'm making progress past the *panda bear* stage.

Comment: So you're a _professional_ riddle/rebus creator? Good to see PSE is being frequented by the 'experts' the mods always wanted to attract! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MONEY?

*In your pocket I'll stay till you send me away;*

> It stays in your pocket until you spend it.

*But keep me a while and I'll build up a pile,*

> Keep it for long enough and it'll pile up like a miser's hoard.

*Lest for desire I'll escape all a-fire.*

> Money can be spent (or escape your possession) on your desires. Alternatively (thanks to Kik), this refers to the expression "money is burning a hole in your pocket".

Comment: You've got the answer; but think about the last line again for the full explanation.

Comment: Kik - you got the last line right though, so you get my vote, but rand got the answer first.

Answer (score 4):

> Money

In your pocket I'll stay till you send me away;

> You keep money in your pocket until you spend it

But keep me a while and I'll build up a pile

> If you save your money, it will add up, and you could also use it to earn additional interest in a savings account, or other investments

Lest for desire I'll escape all a-fire

> The well known phrase "that money is burning a hole in your pocket"

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> a coin/coins

In your pocket I'll stay till you send me away;

> coins stay in your pocket until you spend them

But keep me a while and I'll build up a pile,

> If you don't use your coins you must be using bills and will inevitably get more coins in change. Alternatively you store your coins in a bank and they build interest

Lest for desire I'll escape all a-fire.

> This is my biggest stretch. Unlike bills coins can't be set on fire, and the only way to really get rid of coins is to spend them on your desires

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

> Lint.

*In your pocket I'll stay till you send me away;*

> til you pick it out

*But keep me a while and I'll build up a pile,*

> Lint on the dryer filter

*Lest for desire I'll escape all a-fire.*

> Lint in the drier filter can catch on fire. (desire rhymes with dryer?)

Note:

> Rand wins but LINT WILL NOT BE SILINTSED

Comment: groooaaaaaaaaaannnnnnnn!  Are you picking on me?